# SVN Checkout from a local repository results in errors E170013, E180001, E160029

Tags: svn, checkout, berkeley-db

I am trying to checkout an old SVN repository. This repository has been download to a local PC, as the network where it was placed is shut down. Now I have this local copy of it. However, I am not able to do a checkout of the repository folder, I get the following error messege:

[image]

I use the following command for checkout:

`svn checkout file:///home/jnpe/Documents/mortenbisgaard/Private/.repos/model/trunk model`

Is there something wrong with that? Or am I not able to connect to a local repository?

Comment: Try running `svnadmin recover` against this old repository. Make a backup of the repository beforehand.

Comment: Is this the same issue as [this blog post](https://blog.markhepburn.com/2014/05/18/recovering-svn-bdb-repositories-from-endian-issues/)? "which looks suspiciously like an endianness issue ...  It was created on a PPC Mac and I’m now trying to access it from an Intel box, so that seems like a reasonable explanation."

Comment: Tried svnadmin recover,it resultet in the following:
svnadmin recover Private/.repos/
Repository lock acquired.
Please wait; recovering the repository may take some time...
svnadmin: E160029: BDB0087 DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
svnadmin: E160029: bdb: BDB2530 Ignoring log file: Private/.repos/db/log.0000000460: magic number 88090400, not 40988
svnadmin: E160029: bdb: BDB2527 Invalid log file: log.0000000460: Invalid argument
svnadmin: E160029: bdb: BDB0061 PANIC: Invalid argument

Comment: @Joe seems like that is the same problem as mine, thanks, I will try to follow his footsteps. However some of his links are dead, but I guess I will just have to setup a virtual environment, and then do what he did in the later steps?